# Transform CSV to JSON Parameter

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I am trying to convert a CSV file to a JSON file.

```
library(jsonlite)

test <- read_csv("6_items.csv")
jsoncars <- toJSON(test, pretty=TRUE)
View(jsoncars)
write_json(jsoncars, "6_items.json" )
```

[image]

What parameters need to be changed? How?

Thank you

The CSV File

"Year","Names","Size","Volume","AchsenMax","AchsenMid","AchsenMin","Class","Parts"
2001,"Category1",72,25,72,36,0," Segment",6
2004,"Category2",41,40,72,36,0," Segment",6
2009,"Category2",25,35,72,36,0," Segment",6
2010,"Category3",66,52,72,36,0," Segment",6
2013,"Category1",45,17,72,36,0," Segment",6
2016,"Category1",52,38,72,36,0," Segment",6

Comment: Are you able to provide `6_items.csv` so that I can run the reprex?

Comment: I added the current inputs of a such a csv file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cat` :

```
cat(jsonlite::toJSON(mtcars, pretty=TRUE), file = 'temp.json')
```

It looks like this in json file.

[image]

Replace `mtcars` with you data (`test`).

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to have the .csv file and/or some code to reduplicate the error. Nevertheless, it looks like there are allot of whitespaces (/n), you could try;

```
library(jsonlite)
test <- read_csv("6_items.csv")
test <- trimws(test)
jsoncars <- toJSON(test, pretty=TRUE)
View(jsoncars)
write_json(jsoncars, "6_items.json" )
```

Comment: I added the current inputs of a such a csv file